# Set size chartjs in div

Tags: javascript, chart.js

how can I set the size of this chartjs ? all screen ( height - width )

[Test chart - jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/swtakxo0/1/)

I try with

```
width:100% and height:100%
```

in div canvas , but don't work.

sorry my bad english :(

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/swtakxo0/2/ I'll add that `height: 100%` gets ignored as the chart will attempt to keep the aspect ratio. So you can set height to a px value to have it ignore the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments:

Seems to work for me. I'll add that height: 100% gets ignored as the chart will attempt to keep the aspect ratio. So you can set height to a `px` value to have it ignore the aspect ratio.

The styling was done via css:

```
#chart {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swtakxo0/2

Comment: It is not working. May be it is because new version?